# Spring Boot Rest API Issues

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm trying to implement a Spring Boot Rest API using Spring Data Jdbc with H2 Database.
This is a microservice, and I'm trying to send a POST request to the microservice from an angular app. I know my POST is working correctly from Angular. Inside of microservice, I am trying to save the POST request to a local H2 database.
This should be relatively straight forward based on documentation I've read online, but I am getting error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here are the files I have setup inside my spring boot microservice (titled 'order'):

OrderController.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order;

import java.util.ListIterator;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.clothingfly.order.Model.Item;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.clothingfly.order.Model.Order;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class OrderController {


    @Autowired
    TempOrderRepository orderRepository;

    @PostMapping("/order")
    public Order postOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
      Order _order = orderRepository.save(new Order(order.getId(), order.getAddress(), order.getPayment(), order.getItems()));
      return _order;
    }
}
```

TempOrderRepository.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.clothingfly.order.Model.Order;



public interface TempOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{

}
```

OrderApplication.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OrderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And I have a model named Order.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order.Model;


import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "Payment")
    private PaymentInfo payment;

    @Column(name = "Items")
    private List<Item> items;

    @Column(name = "Error")
    private String error;

    public Order() {

    }

    public Order(long id, Address address, PaymentInfo payment, List<Item> items){
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
        this.payment = payment;
        this.items = items;
        this.error = "";
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public PaymentInfo getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }


    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

}
```

The Order model takes in three other models:
Item.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private long quantity;

    @Column(name = "inventory")
    private long inventory;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public long getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public String getImageUrl(){
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setInventory(long inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setQuantity(long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Item(long id, String name, float price, long quantity, long inventory, String imageUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.inventory = inventory;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Item() {

  }
}
```

Address.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order.Model;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

  @Column(name = "firstName")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "lastName")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "address")
  private String address;

  @Column(name = "country")
  private String country;

  @Column(name = "apartmentNo")
  private String apartmentNo;

  @Column(name = "state")
  private String state;

  @Column(name = "city")
  private String city;

  @Column(name = "zipcode")
  private String zipcode;


  public Address() {

  }

  public Address(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String country, String apartmentNo, String state,
            String city, String zipcode) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.country = country;
    this.apartmentNo = apartmentNo;
    this.state = state;
    this.city = city;
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
  }

  public String getApartmentNo() {
    return apartmentNo;
  }

  public void setApartmentNo(String apartmentNo) {
    this.apartmentNo = apartmentNo;
  }

  public String getState() {
    return state;
  }

  public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }

  public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
  }

  public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
  }
}
```

PaymentInfo.java:

```
package com.clothingfly.order.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
public class PaymentInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

  @Column(name = "cardHolder")
  private String cardHolder;

  @Column(name = "cardNumber")
  private String cardNumber;

  @Column(name = "expirationDate")
  private String expirationDate;

  @Column(name = "cvv")
  private String cvv;



  public PaymentInfo(String cardHolder, String cardNumber, String expirationDate, String cvv) {
    this.cardHolder = cardHolder;
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    this.cvv = cvv;
  }

  public String getCardHolder() {
    return cardHolder;
  }

  public void setCardHolder(String cardHolder) {
    this.cardHolder = cardHolder;
  }

  public String getCardNumber() {
    return cardNumber;
  }

  public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
  }

  public String getExpirationDate() {
    return expirationDate;
  }

  public void setExpirationDate(String expirationDate) {
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
  }

  public String getCvv() {
    return cvv;
  }

  public void setCvv(String cvv) {
    this.cvv = cvv;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to run microservice:
`Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.clothingfly.order.Model.Address, at table: orders, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(address)]`

How would I go about fixing this?
I want to be able to display all of my models inside a table.

I tried changing Address model so that it only returns a string of the city, but that seemed to cause more issues than anything.

Comment: Can you please share the database table structure?

Comment: You've got @Column(name = "Items") for all your Object references. You'll need to go through a JPA tutorial to help you through modeling your entities and relationships, but the column annotation tells JPA which database table "column" to use for the property/field it is on - not a separate table as you seem to be expecting. It needs more in many cases to determine how to serialize  an Address or List<Item> into a single column. If you remove the column annotations, it will try to use defaults to the referenced entities which may work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, one to one will always cause you an issue, always better to implement `many to one and one to many`. and add it to both entities you are mapping. It will do the same job with no errors.

First, create packages, and don't place everything in one package.
create

```
package com.clothingfly.repo or  com.clothingfly.order.repo
package com.clothingfly.controller or  com.clothingfly.order.controller
```

Secondly, add the annotation `@Repository` to your repository interface

```
package com.clothingfly.repo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.clothingfly.order.Model.Order;


@Repository
public interface TempOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{

}
```

Thirdly, add the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.clothingfly.repo")` to your main application class.

```
package com.clothingfly.order;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.clothingfly.repo")
public class OrderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Lastly, this will not work correctly. Not sure what you are doing here.

```
@Column(name = "Address")
private Address address;
```

Try this:
add this in your address entity

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable = false)// add this column 
    // order_id in your Address database not the entity
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;
```

Then, add this to your Order class.

```
       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        @JsonIgnore
        List<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>(); // I use list cause sometimes it throws an error
// try to simply use this, if it throws expection then use the list
      //private Address address;
```

Your Order constructor should be like:

```
public Order(long id, List<Address> address ...etc
```

Or simply

```
public Order(long id, Address address ...etc
```

Do this for all your mapped entities and don't forget to add setters and getters for all fields.

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell hibernate that the Address object is coming from another table and how to join those tables, since your orders table most likely does not have a column which contains the hole address but the the address id/ primary key of the address as foreign key.
this is possible, depending if you have 1:1, 1:n, n:1 or n:m relations with the corresponding @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany annotations.
for your example it could be something like

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Address address;
```

Comment: I have an Address model which contains id, firstname, lastname, address, country, city, state, zipcode. Inside of Order Model, I want a column which connect the Order table to the Address table. Each Order will only have one address object associated with it, so I believe it should be 1:1. When I try to and run code using your above statement, I am getting error 500 response back in Angular project when I send POST request.